# Footnote in math mode: \footnotemark in math + \footnotetext does not work

Tags: math-mode, footnotes

Since directly typing `\footnote{...}` in math mode is not allowed, the common approach is to type `\footnotemark` in the math and write `\footnotetext{...}` after the math. However, when the math is located to the bottom of a page, the line containing `\footnotetext{...}` is on the second page, causing the misplacement of the actual footnote. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgffor} % for \foreach

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,43}
{The \x th fictional space-taking line.

}

\[
fictional + math + formula \footnotemark
\]\footnotetext{This is a fictional footnote. See the weird behavior?}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image: page 1][image: page 2]

Comment: It is never a good idea to add footnotes in math, how do a reader tell the difference from a power?

Comment: I know that, but sometimes that is unavoidable. The symbols can be redefined, though. But this example is completely *fictional* :P

Comment: It is always avoidable. I'm guessing that the footnotetext is leaving behind a whatsit and is therefore leaving something on the vertical list and is then moved to the next page. You probably needs to add it before the math and get creative with the counters. But again don't ever do this, rewrite!

Comment: I think using `\footnote` inside the equation environment should just work in this case. It would not work inside any of the `amsmath` math environments or inside e.g. `\text{}` within the equation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it inside the equation:

```
\[
fictional + math + formula \footnotemark
\footnotetext{This is a fictional footnote. See the weird behavior?}
\]
```

Comment: I too followed the same if footnote occurs in math